# Can multiple summoned creatures Help multiple allies gain Advantage through one verbal command?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, advantage-and-disadvantage, helping

If a player's character summons N creatures, say for example 10 Giant Centipedes using Giant Insect, and immediately uses his free action to verbally command them en masse to use their Help Action to "help me and my allies attack that enemy by distracting it", would that grant 10 advantages total for the next 10 attacks against that enemy until the player's next turn, regardless who made them? Or, can they only Help me, the summoner who commanded them to Help.

EDIT: This should not be Closed and needs an answer as the question stands on it's own merit. The answer linked is moot because this isn't the issue of whether the summoned creatures choose the target (they were told it, and RAW clearly they do anyway). Nor is it that the PC chose the Help action (he didn't). There was not a single Help action taken in this example. There were multiple (up to 10 depending on positioning).

The crux of the issue is do these N Help actions all, COMBINED, offer *ONE* attack, ie, "the next attack" made at advantage against the enemy creature? Or, do they stack, and they offer N advantages?

I do not see how the linked answer actually answers that question.

Comment: Very related: [Do I choose the target or the ally for the Help action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128393)

Comment: I think I've found a suitable duplicate, it seems to be exactly your question here. Let me know if it doesn't answer your question (and why) and we can see about clarifying the situation here.

Comment: That seems related for sure, but isn't asking the same question.

Clearly, those creatures are all pestering the same creature in combat. They don't choose which ally they help (that would be out of combat), in combat they choose which creature they will impact.

Do those N helping creatures affect the next attack against it? Or the next N attacks?

They are all doing what they do, the Help, at the same time, as they all act on the summoner's turn.

RAW, each of them are affecting "the next attack".

So is that all the SAME attack? Or, do they stack up?

Comment: What you have explained seems to be what that question is asking, and it's definitely the question the accepted answer addresses. The accepted answer directly responds to the questions of your above comment.

Comment: Kirt, perhaps I'm wrong, that seems incorrect RAW as there is nothing in the Help action which says that the creatures must REMAIN in the adjacent space for the entire *round* for their ally to gain advantage. On their *turn* they can dart in, feign (Help), and move out. Furthermore, even though they are all on the same Initiative, they  each have an opportunity to act and carry out their movement and action, in order.

Regardless, it's not the crux of my question. It was just an example. The point is, N creatures that are under the control ONE verbal command can surround the enemy.

Comment: @Kirt According to [the SAC](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA122), "If you use the Help action to distract a foe, do you have to stay within 5 feet of it for the action to work? No, you can take the action and then move away. The action itself is what grants advantage to your ally, not your staying next to the foe."

Comment: "do these N Help actions all, COMBINED, offer ONE attack, ie, "the next attack" made at advantage against the enemy creature? Or, do they stack, and they offer N advantages?" This is exactly the question Ryan C. Thompson's answer examines in detail.